# What is __m128d?

Tags: c++, intel, intrinsics, sse2

I really can't get what "keyword" like `__m128d` is in C++.

I'm using MSVC, and [it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/m128d?view=vs-2017) says: `The __m128d data type, for use with the Streaming SIMD Extensions 2 instructions intrinsics, is defined in <emmintrin.h>`.

So, is it a Data Type? `typedef`? If I do:

```
#include <emmintrin.h>

int main() {
    __m128d x;
}
```

I can't see the defination on `<emmintrin.h>`. It seems a `keyword` of compiler? Does it automatically convert that keyword to somethings like "move register xmm0" etc? Or which kind of operation does?

It doesn't seems a data type at all.

Can someone shine me?

Comment: A 128 bit register?

Comment: It represents an XMM register of 128 bit width.

Comment: Yes it _is_ a typedef. Look closely at the `<emmintrin.h>` file.

Comment: https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/emmintrin_8h_source.html line 29?

Comment: Think of `__m128d` in the same way that would a `double` - in your code it's just a type, but under the hood it could be a memory location, a register, some combination of both, or even optimised away completely.

Comment: @PaulR: what do you mean with "or even optimised away completely."?

Comment: @markzzz: just as with any other simple variable type it's perfectly possible for the compiler to obviate the need for a temporary value that is represented in your code as a variable (this is one of the things that makes using a debugger with optimised code quite tricky, as variables in the source code may not even exist in the generated binary).

Comment: @PaulR but its still on register. Or do you mean as "const" that it simply written in the asm?

Comment: @markzzz: there are a number of code generation optimisations that can cause a variable to "disappear", e.g. an explicit load and a subsequent arithmetic operation  in your code could be elided into a single arithmetic instruction with a memory operand instead of a register operand. Here is [an example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/OXHwDJ) - note that `v1` "disappears".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it a typedef?

Yes!

`__m128d` is a data type that the compiler will hopefully store in a XMM 128 bit register when optimizing (if not optimizing it away as @PeterCordes commented).  It's not inherently different from an `int` or `long`, which the compiler will hopefully store in integer registers when optimizing.

**The actual definition is compiler-specific**; code that intends to be portable between MSVC and the other major compilers that implement Intel's intrinsics should avoid depending on the details of the definition.

MSVC defines vector types as a union of arrays of different element sizes.

In compilers that implement GNU C extensions (gcc and clang), it is typedef'ed as a 16-byte GNU C native vector of `double`s:

```
// From gcc 7.3's emmintrin.h  (SSE2 extensions).  SSE1 stuff in xmmintrin.h

/* The Intel API is flexible enough that we must allow aliasing with other
   vector types, and their scalar components.  */
typedef long long __m128i __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (16), __may_alias__));
typedef double __m128d __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (16), __may_alias__));
```

in [`<emmintrin.h>`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/emmintrin_8h_source.html), as @Default commented.

The `may_alias` attribute tells the compiler that `__m128d*` can alias other types the same way that `char*` can, for the purposes of optimization based on C++ strict-aliasing rules.

---

Example of usage: (initialization is portable between MSVC and other compilers)

```
__m128d a2 = { -1.388539L, 0.0L };
```

---

---

For `__m128`, check the [Intel forum](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/362267) and [`<xmmintrin.h>`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/xmmintrin_8h_source.html).

Comment: It's not literally a register, just like `int foo;` isn't literally an integer register.  It's a C variable that the compiler will hopefully keep in a register when optimizing, if it doesn't optimize away.  It's a data type that can map to an XMM register.

Comment: @PeterCordes indeed, injected that to my answer, thanks!

Comment: You edited out the MSVC definition, and had an old or simplified version of the GNU C definition.  I fixed that for you, and added a big warning that it *is* different between implementations.  I'm not 100% sure how Intel's own compiler defines it.  ICC implements GNU C extensions, so it does support GNU C native vectors.  But IDK if they define `__m128` in terms of native vectors the way gcc does.